# how to INSERT INTO for each updates row

Tags: sql, insert, sql-update

Have a SQL INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO [tbAddress]
           ([CompanyName])
 VALUES
           ('undefined'),
```

and UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE tbOrganisation
SET AddressID=INSERT INTO [tbAddress]
           ([CompanyName])
     VALUES
           ('undefined' )

WHERE AddressID = 783240
```

I need insert to table `Address` new same record for each record with `AddressID = 783240`, help please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `SCOPE_IDENTITY`:

```
    DECLARE @addressId int

    INSERT INTO [tbAddress] ([CompanyName]) VALUES ('undefined')
    SET @addressId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE tbOrganisation SET AddressID = @addressId WHERE AddressID = 783240
```

More information on Technet here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx. Note that you may come across @@IDENTITY as another solution, however there are subtle differences (I believe, related to triggers).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understood the question, but I think this should help:

```
UPDATE tbOrganisation SET AddressID='undefined' WHERE AddressID=783240;
```

Is this what you had in mind?